# How can I display different integer values for the Edit and create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code as part of my view which is used for both Edit Or Create new entities:-

```
<div >
    <span class="f">RAM (in MB) </span> 

    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY)

</div>
```

How can I display different integer values for the Edit and create view.
I have the following code as part of my view which is used for both Edit Or Create new entities:-
But am dealing with third party database which will store the total memory by multiplying it will 1 million . so when creating a new object the user will enter 2 MB , it will be stored as 2,000,000. So when editing an entity I need to display only 2 . but currently on the edit it will display the value As-IS from the database which is 2,000,000. Any idea how I can solve this will keep using the same view for create and edit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add an additional property to your model for the view only and ensure that is in megabytes for the view in the controller and then convert back as part of the save. That way your display is always in megabytes and the database is in bytes. (Or have I missed something?)